# How to preserve path structure with PHP include?

Tags: php, css, include

I have a toolbarMenu.php that uses css in a css directory ("css") from the root folder.

All of my other PHP forms are in a root folder, and planned to re-organize all my PHP form to be move to a new folder called "forms" exluding toolbarMenu.php

After I move my PHP form to sub-directory, I can call this toolbarMenu.php by using include
ex:

```
<?php include("../toolbar-top.php"); ?>
```

However, the CSS path broke because it's trying to look for the css folder inside the forms folder. I don't want to change the css path from my toolbarMenu.php to "../css/file.css" because I'm also using this php page with the website's root pages.

Is there a way to preserve the toolbarMenu.php's css path when it's being called from a PHP form from another sub-directory?

From Root folder:

Toolbar Menu path: "toolbarMenu.php"

CSS path: "css/cssFile.css"

PHP form calling the ToolbarMenu: "forms/form.php"

I hope I made my question clear :)

Thanks!

Comment: so the references to the css in toolbarMenu.php are broken because he is trying to access them from folder <forms>?

Comment: yes.. from my toolbarMenu.php.. the css path is "css/cssFile.css" since toolbarMenu.php is being called from another PHP form from a subdirectory "forms", that form is looking for "css/cssFile.css" but if I change it to "../css/cssFile.css" it works.. but I don't want to change it natively, because other page from the root directory uses it the toolbarMenu.php as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either use an absolute path, eg

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/mySite/css/file.css">
```

or, if you want to keep it portable, set a dynamic `<base>` for relative paths. This way you can move your entire app to a sub-directory without breaking reference links, eg

```
<!-- in HEAD -->
<base href="http://localhost/mySite/">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/file.css">
```

Comment: i'm currently using localhost. how would I use localhost as my base?  I tried <base href="http://localhost/mySite"> but it didn't work

Comment: @Arnold Don't forget the trailing slash. Try `<base href="http://localhost/mySite/">`. I've updated my answer to match your environment better

Comment: this one works, adding the extra "/" at the end was the issue. thank so you much!

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple options to get the desired result:

1. You can define a prefix variable/constant at the top of every page which you then use in all your includes/urls/etc.
2. You can also use the `<base>` tag in your header pointing to the absolute URL to `../` so something like `http://ys.cc/proj/` if your `forms` directory is `http://ys.cc/proj/forms`

Answer (score 0):

You can write your css file selector from:

```
css/file.css
```

to

```
/css/file.css
```

This will work in all folders.

Comment: @arnold-porche-villaluz The difference between those two is guaranteed behavior. If that didn't work, there's something wrong.

Comment: @Christian The OP confused us by saying the `css` directory was in the "root" directory. Looks like it's actually in a `mySite` sub-directory